# Building a Riemannian metric through perscribed Christoffel symbols

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose I have $d^3$ many class $C^{1}$ functions $f_{i,j,k}:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  Are there precise requirements on $f_{i,j,k}$ in order for there to exist a Riemannian metric $g_t$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ whose Christoffel symbols
$$
\Gamma_{i,j}^k = f_{i,j,k}?
$$

Comment: Do you mean whose Levi-Civita connection has the given Christoffel symbols? If so then a necessary condition is $f_{ijk} = f_{jik}$.

Comment: Indeed, but is this also sufficient?

Comment: One would expect not (for $d > 1$),, since a metric depends locally on $d^2$ functions but, even after we impose the above symmetry we're still prescribing $\frac 1 2 (d + 1) d^2$ functions

Comment: Actually, in my case, I only really need $f_{i,j,1}$ specified (and I can assume symmetry in i and j); for k>1 I actually have no restrictions...so maybe this is still possible (in my case)

Comment: Of course I should have said that a metric depends locally on $\frac 12 d (d + 1)$ functions.

Comment: Right, so in this case it should work no?  Or do I need additional smoothness in $f_{i,j,1}$?

Comment: Not every affine connection $\nabla$ preserves a Riemannian metric. One way to say that it does is to require that the holonomy group of $\nabla$ is relatively compact.

Comment: Hmmm, this I will look into; it sounds promising!  Any references on how this links directly to the Christoffel symbols (I've never worked with holonomy groups before).

Comment: @AIM_BLB Is the question, "Given functions $f_{ij1}$ with $f_{ij1} = f_{ji1}$, is there a metric $g_{ij}$ for which the Christoffel symbols (w.r.t. the usual coordinate frame) satisfy $\Gamma_{ij}^1 = f_{ij1}$?" If so, I'm not sure off hand---the fact that the number of functions specified agrees with the number of functions available in specifying $f$ does not guarantee existence of a solution.

Comment: In principle one way of proceeding naively would be to generate a complete set of differential conditions on $f$ by differentiating $\Gamma_{ij}^k$, writing out the second Christoffel identity, and eliminating $g$ to derive differential conditions satisfied by the $\Gamma_{ij}^k$, then check whether we can specify, e.g., $\Gamma_{ij}^1$ freely.

Comment: Christoffel symbols is just a way to describe a connection in coordinates. As for holonomy, it is a complicated condition, which involves solving a system of ODEs. Lie algebra is a bit easier to describe, it is generated by linear transformations $R(X,Y)$, where $R$ is the curvature of $\nabla$. The compactness condition then corresponds to the condition that the Killing form of this Lie algebra is negative definite. It's still a complicated condition but the problem is reduced to linear algebra.

Comment: Like Moishe says, not every affine connection preserves a Riemannian metric. In fact, in a sense that can be made precise, most affine connections are not even projectively equivalent to a connection (i.e., have the same geodesics as a connection) which preserves a Riemannian metric, or any nonzero symmetric, bilinear form, for that matter. The perspective of deciding whether a connection is projectively equivalent to a metrizable connection is useful in part because it is governed by a projectively invariant linear differential operator.

Comment: From this point of view the problem is essentially solved in dimension $2$ in https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0300 and dimension $3$ in https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06191 . Treating the problem of whether a connection is itself metrizable is perhaps simpler, but I do not know offhand where this is treated.

Comment: There is a lot of reading, I'll have to take a look, give it some thought, and get back to you two in a few days (rather than rush a comment at the moment).  Thank you both very much.

Comment: Cheers, glad to help. I've only glanced at the paper, but this article seems to treat the problem of whether a 2D connection is metrizable in some detail: https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/137517/ActaOlom_48-2009-1_14.pdf

Comment: Thanks again Travis, I think this will all help very much :)